# Capturing return code with test []

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

If I run this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

simple_return_zero(){
  return 0;
}

simple_return_one(){
  return 1;
}

if [ simple_return_zero ]; then
   echo "we have 0000";
fi

if [ ! simple_return_zero ]; then
   echo "we have not 00000";
fi

if [ simple_return_one ]; then
   echo "we have 11111";
fi

if [ ! simple_return_one ]; then
   echo "we have not 11111";
fi
```

I get:

```
we have 0000
we have 11111
```

I know the above is the wrong code to use, I think this is the right way to do it:

```
if simple_return_zero; then
   echo "we have 0000";
fi

if ! simple_return_zero; then
   echo "we have not 00000";
fi

if simple_return_one; then
   echo "we have 11111";
fi

if ! simple_return_one; then
   echo "we have not 11111";
fi
```

and now we get something more expected:

```
we have 0000
we have not 11111
```

My question is - why doesn't the test command ( [ ] ) work in this case? Doesn't the test command check for exit codes / return codes???

Comment: also, if there is a better way to run/organize the code, pls lmk...it's a little awkward with the ! in front of the command without any  [ ] braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Doesn't the test command check for exit codes / return codes???

**Absolutely not.** It performs the test as defined by the text within the brackets, whose syntax can be viewed via `help test`.

`if` on its own checks the return code of the command executed.

Comment: humma but what does test actually do if there is no comparison operator? for example if it's just a command in between the brackets?

Comment: From `help test`: "STRING      True if string is not empty."

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, fml